Why are my benchmark times not repeatable, even for a CPU-bound task?
I'm running some benchmarks on my Linux desktop/laptop computer, but I'm not getting reliable results. I'm running a CPU-intensive task that does negligible I/O and doesn't use much RAM. My computer is multicore and not doing much. So I expect only slight variations between runs. But I see huge variations.
$ bash -c 'x=0; time while ((x < 999999)); do ((++x)); done'

real    0m2.281s
user    0m2.279s
sys     0m0.001s
$ bash -c 'x=0; time while ((x < 999999)); do ((++x)); done'

real    0m0.906s
user    0m0.906s
sys     0m0.000s
$ bash -c 'x=0; time while ((x < 999999)); do ((++x)); done'

real    0m1.030s
user    0m1.030s
sys     0m0.000s

There seems to be a cluster of fast times and a cluster of slow times, with the occasional thing in between. The variability between fast times is small enough for my purposes, and the variability between slow times is small enough for my purposes. But I can't work reliably when I don't know if I'm getting a slow time or a fast time or an in-between time.
The variability is in user time, and the real time is almost equal to the user time (it's a single-threaded task). So the problem isn't that some other process is sharing the CPU. What's going on, and how can I get reliable benchmarks for a CPU-bound task on my PC?

Always ignore the first run.  After the first run, all the files are in the disk cache (executables, libraries, configuration files, application files, etc.).

TL, DR:
sudo cpupower -c 0 frequency-set -g performance
taskset -c 0 ./my-benchmark
…
sudo cpupower -c 0 frequency-set -g powersave

Explanation
What's going on is that the processor in a modern computer doesn't always run at the same speed. When the processor isn't doing much, it runs more slowly. When the kernel detects that a processor is consistently busy, it increases the frequency. When the kernel detects that a processor is spending a lot of time idle, it reduces the frequency. This is called CPU frequency scaling. Linux has several different modes for deciding how to scale the frequency, called governors.
This explains the effect where the first run of a benchmark is slower than subsequent runs: the processor is warming up. (Both metaphorically in the sense of going faster, and literally: the reason processors aren't kept at their maximum speed all the time is that this consumes a lot of energy so it makes them become very hot.)
In a multicore CPU, each core (or group of cores) has its own frequency setting. This can cause stranger patterns where a run of a benchmark starts running on one core, which speeds up, then the next run gets another core which was slow and speeds up, and so on. Even during one run of the benchmark, the benchmark process can migrate between cores at any context switch, and those cores might be running at different speeds, but the kernel tends to keep a given process on the same core when not much else is happening.
Solution
For a reasonably reproducible benchmark:

Pick a core, and pin it to a given speed.
Pin the benchmark to that core.

The following command makes core 0 run fast:
sudo cpupower -c 0 frequency-set -g performance

Equivalently, you can use the /sys interface directly:
echo performance | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor

Now, pin your benchmark to CPU 0 for more repeatable timings:
taskset -c 0 ./my-benchmark

Don't forget to reset the CPU scaling when you're done, so that it doesn't keep running hot.
sudo cpupower -c 0 frequency-set -g powersave

If your benchmark is parallelized, you can scale multiple CPUs and pass a list of CPUs to taskset, e.g. taskset -c 0,1,2,3 ./my-benchmark or equivalently taskset -c 0-3 ./my-benchmark.
Note that taskset only forces the benchmark to use a given (set of) CPU, it doesn't keep other processes from using that CPU as well. (But if the system is lightly loaded, the other processes will mostly run on other CPUs, since the kernel prefers using a different CPU to making processes compete for time on the same CPU.) If you want to dedicate a CPU to your benchmarks, Linux can do that, but it's a lot more involved. See Telling Linux kernel *not* to use certain CPUs
More information
The following commands illustrate how to get information about the current CPU scaling.
cpupower -c 0 frequency-info      # info about core 0
cpupower -c all frequency-info    # info about all cores
cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor    # how the kernel decides
cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_available_governors  # how the kernel can decide
cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq    # lowest possible speed
cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq    # current speed
cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq    # highest possible speed


You could also mention preemption latency and random delays which can be introduced by interrupts being handled on the CPUs. In the simple benchmark described in the question, I nearly always get stable result if I use RT-enabled kernel. As I understand, it is achieved through allowing context switch in more cases (i.e. interrupts which are converted to preemptable threads in the RT kernel). Does the CPU scaling (which you described) really do much effect on that simple benchmark? I'm using RT kernel + schedutil governor. And I get nearly equal time values between runs.

@melonfsck In my case, I'm running the benchmarks on my own machine, and I don't need high precision, just within a few percent. Interrupts and other context switches takes negligible impact (maybe 1%). I'm not going to use a special kernel or special kernel options: this is an ordinary PC for everyday tasks. The CPU scaling range is about 1:6 on this particular machine, and for a CPU-bound task, this can mean a 1:6 range for execution times.

One other note, in case you're benchmarking Java: The Hotspot JIT compiler is nondeterministic; it may optimize differently every time. Drove me crazy while trying to tune a compiler. (Yes, some would say that was a short trip.)

If you care about latency after idle, you shouldn't turn off performance mode of the CPU but fix the cooling instead. For shortest possible latency on x86-64 hardware you may also need to disable CPU idle modes deeper than C1 (e.g. C1E, C2, ... cause extra latency when you start a new task). There doesn't seem to exist any solution that allows low latency and low power usage. You can try to run following to reduce latency: cyclictest --mlockall --threads=1 --priority=99 --interval=10000000 --latency=5  --quiet – as long as this is running, your CPU will not allow more than 5 µs latency.

In addition to Gilles' answer, contemporary CPUs are very complex, with branch predictors, readahead units, multiple levels of cache, and multiple cores that interact with each other and need to share some internal busses. All these things might need to "warm up": caches need to be populated, branch predictors need to learn patterns, and so on. The operating system is also doing many things and introduces similar issues. Apart from frequency scaling, memory allocation and disk caching might also take a while before they are warmed up.
Typically, you should add a warm-up phase to your benchmark, where you do exactly the same as in the actual benchmark, but you just don't do any timing yet. How long you have to do this warm-up phase for depends on many things, and it's usually longer than you think. You can check by repeatedly doing some amount of work and record how long it takes, and then look for when that time becomes more stable.

This. In particular, hyperthreading cores are especially affected. Apart from running benchmarks in pre-warmed single-user mode (with no other apps including system daemons), to reduce the effect of such errors, one could also increase the benchmark running time. In example above, the number of loops should be increased by at least an order or two of magnitude.That would reduce small fixed errors (e.g. 0.5s error is huge deal if your benchmark runs for ~3 seconds; however if it runs for ~300 seconds it is completely ignorable. And ~30 seconds is usually good enough compromise)
